# How do I separate jdbc.properties and my deployed JAR or WAR application file

Tags: hibernate, swing, jakarta-ee, properties

I want my user to easily change `jdbc.properties` in my deployed application. User doesn't want to extract compiled JAR or WAR file, edit `jdbc.properties`, and zip it again. I googled for the solution a while but still not find the answer.

I use Spring and Hibernate using DAO.

Here is my applicationContext.xml for jdbc:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties" />
```

I tried to change it to `classpath:../jdbc.properties`, etc and locate `jdbc.properties` in all possible location but still not work.

Is it possible to do that? If it is not possible, how can my application load specified `jdbc.properties` location that is hard-coded?

Note: This is used for separate Development and Production phase in my workplace. So Developer guy doesn't know specification on Production side.

Answer (score 1):

Many App servers (for example JBoss or Websphere) support "exploded .war's" the .war (or .ear) is literally a directory and you can manipulate the files directly.

Otherwise, it sounds like a job for JMX:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/agent.html
- http://marxsoftware.blogspot.com/2008/03/spring-jmx-configuration-with-xml.html